# Alternative of SQL Server for .Net applications

Tags: .net, sql

I am planning to create a .Net web application (using C# and ADO.Net) which will replace the currently used MS Excel file for tracking requirements.
However, I cannot use SQL Server as backend due to permission issues.
Can anyone please suggest me some other way to store the data being send from UI.
Thanks in advance for any help regd this problem.

Comment: What are your constraints exactly, shared hosting and there is no sql server support? You need something free?

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest you SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0. This is a stable, free, embeded database with a native support of EF CF.

If you need something with "engine", then you can refer to PostgreSQL.

**Edit**

Actually, possibilities are endless. You can use SQLite, VistaDB if you need something embedded. On the other hand there are oracle, DB2, Informix and even mySQL is supported.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on your situation and the reason you cannot use SQL Server.

If you can't use SQL Server because of licensing issues (cost), you can use SQL Server Express for lots of scenarios. It has limitations that SQL Server does not have (database size being one) but uses the same underlying engine so gives a perfect upgrade path should you decide to move to full-blown SQL Server in the future.

If you are only using the system on one computer and like the SQL Server model, you can use SQL Server Compact Edition, as Oybek mentioned. This has a lot of limitations over SQL Server so the upgrade path is not as simple but is not too onerous. The benefit is that it does not require a server installation.

There are lots of other database systems out there that .NET can talk to; far too many to mention. Many of the relational databases are listed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_relational_database_management_systems). You caould also consider No-SQL alternatives.

Finally, if it's a single user system using Excel that you are replacing, you could even retain the data in Excel using VSTO. This is much more complex way of doing things though and upgrade possibilities are virtually nil.

It's worthwhile editing the question to explain further what your requirements and constraints are.

Answer (score -2):

U CAN Use any kind of database store u want , there are tons of free data base such as Mysql for example

Comment: Thanks everyone for your responses. The reason why i cant use SQL Server is that the new application will reside on client machine and I will not get permission to create a new database in the SQL Server which is already present on that machine. Moreover, this application will be made accessible to multiple users. So, please suggest me something in this scenario. Thanks :)