# C# VSTO with DBMS

Tags: c#, mongodb, vsto, database

Is it possible to use any other DBMS that is not Microsoft Access to VSTO, I would like to use mongodb. Do you see any advantage?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is Yes.

Refer to the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9052934/alternative-of-sql-server-for-net-applications/9052947#9052947) for more information.

As far as the second question is concerned, what advantage do you expect?
What are your technical requirements and constraints? Budget? Already existing platform? Migrations?

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO), is a rich development environment allowing you almost the same level of flexibility as with any C# application.  You can reference assemblies for any number of database providers within the solution, including MongoDB.

Just add a reference to your MongoDB provider to the project and interact with it as you normally do.